# Sitecore 8: Deleting a language has caused the KeyNotFoundException Exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have deleted "Danish" language from sitecore. In my solution I am getting exception, where ever I have used the code `Sitecore.Context.Language.Name`.

Here is the exception

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

The whole stack trace

```
Source Error: 
Line 22:         static Model.Localization.CommonDictionary GetCommonLocalizations()
Line 23:         {
Line 24:             return Dictionary[Sitecore.Context.Language.Name];
Line 25:         }
Line 26:         public static string DefaultActivityTitle { get { return GetCommonLocalizations().DefaultActivityTitle; } }

Source File:  E:\IIS Data\MySite\Utilities\SF.ISK.Kernel\Localisation\CommonDictionary.cs    Line:  24 

Stack Trace: 
[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +13763207
   SF.ISK.Kernel.Localisation.CommonDictionary.GetCommonLocalizations() in E:\IIS Data\MySite\Utilities\SF.ISK.Kernel\Localisation\CommonDictionary.cs:24
   SF.ISK.Kernel.Localisation.CommonDictionary.get_HtmlTitleTemplate() in E:\IIS Data\MySite\Utilities\SF.ISK.Kernel\Localisation\CommonDictionary.cs:136
   SF.ISK.Website.layouts.ISK.ISKMainPageLayout.GetPageTitle() in E:\IIS Data\MySite\Website\layouts\ISK\ISK.MainPage.aspx.cs:51
   SF.ISK.Website.layouts.ISK.ISKMainPageLayout.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\IIS Data\MySite\Website\layouts\ISK\ISK.MainPage.aspx.cs:41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498
```

**In above code if I replace it with `return Dictionary["en"];` then I don't get the error.**

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: And what is the value of `Sitecore.Context.Language.Name`? Is it `da-DA`? Try to debug and see

Comment: Yes its still gives me `da`.

Comment: It means that either `Sitecore.Context.Items["sc_Language"]` is set to `da`, or your site `lang` cookie is set to `da` or site default language is set to `da` or `DefaultLanguage` setting is set to `da` or you're inside language switcher block.

Comment: How can I check/set the default language in Sitecore 8 ?

Comment: You can set `DefaultLanguage` setting in your configs. But if you haven't set anything, it will default to `en`. And all the other cookies etc (mentioned in previous comment) have higher priority

Comment: Well I have deleted all the cookies and I have not set any default language in web.config. I will check for languageSwitcher in the code..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your item has a version da-dk. Remove the da-dk version  and publish.

It might be that while looking for da-dk which has been deleted, sitecore is unable to find this key.